# Polynomial that is symmetric in some variables

Tags: reference-request, symmetric-polynomials

I would like to construct (or determine the existence/inexistence) of a polynomial $p(x_1,...,x_k, y_1,...,y_n)$ satisfying the following properties:

1. $p$ is symmetric with relation to the variables $x_1,...,x_k$, in the sense that swapping any two of these variables do not alter the polynomial. Observe that for the variables $y_i$ no symmetry condition is imposed.
2. $p$ has degree at most $k-1$.
3. each variable in $\{x_1,...,x_k,y_1,...,y_n\}$ appears in at most $k-2$  monomials.
4. $p$ is connected. By connectedness I mean that the graph whose vertices are monomials, and whose edges connect monomials having a common variable, is connected.

My question is: Given $k\in \mathbb{N}$, does such a polynomial $p(x_1,...,x_k,y_1,...,y_n)$ exists? Here the number $n$ of $y$ variables can be as large as needed.

Observation: The problem becomes trivial if any of the conditions above are removed. In particular no y variable is needed in this case.

1. If p is not required to be connected, just take the polynomial 
          $p=x_1+ x_2 + ... + x_k$
2. If p can have degree k, then just take $p= x_1x_2...x_k$
3. If a variable can appear in k-1 monomials, then take the polynomial 
   $p=\sum_{i\neq j} x_1x_j$.

I would appreciate any proof of existence/inexistence of such polynomials, or a construction. References dealing with polynomials that are symmetric only in some variables are also welcome.

Answer (score 7):

There are none.

Write it in the monomial basis with respect to $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, with coefficients being polynomials in $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. The only monomial basis functions with $k$ variables such that each variable occurs in at most $k-2$ terms are 1, $x_1^s+\cdots+x_k^s$ for $s\ge 1$, and $x_1^t x_2^t\cdots x_k^t$ for $t\ge 1$. (Because: if a monomial has $r$ variables there are at least $\binom kr$ similar monomials and each $x_j$ appears in at least $\frac kr \binom kr =\binom{k-1}{r-1}$ of them, which is more than $k-2$ unless $r\in\lbrace 0,1,k\rbrace$.) The function $x_1^t x_2^t\cdots x_k^t$ has too high a degree, so the only chances have the form $$p(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = r(\mathbf{y}) + \sum_s q_s(\mathbf{y})(x_1^s+\cdots+x_k^s).$$ We must have $q_s(\mathbf{y})$ independent of $\mathbf{y}$ (i.e. constant) for each $s$, or else some $y_j$ occurs in at least $k$ monomials.  But then $p$ is disconnected.